# I have 5 dimension points (x,y,z,w,v)

Tags: 3d, projection

I have an image of made of points of (x,y). I want to combine the hsv color space of these points so that I have (x,y,h,s,v)
Now how do I project these 5D points onto a 2D image?
I found some link that says to project 
5D onto 4D it's P(x,y,z,w,v) = 1/(1-v)(x,y,z,w) and 
4D onto 3D it's P(x,y,z,w)   = 1/(1-w)(x,y,z) and
3D onto 2D it's P(x,y,z)     = 1/(1-z)(x,y) and
I tried doing the above but all i got was my image is a little warped but generally remained the same just upside down.
I expected or thought that it would warp into something abstract and not recognizable at least that's what I was hoping for.
Am I doing it it right? Or how can I get a more warped abstracted perspective
I don't know what it's supposed to look like it's just experimentation and I have no idea what it's supposed to look like because it's 5D and I have problem imagining 5D. But I was expecting my result to look more warped as a 4D cube drawn in 2D looks way more warped and multidimensional than a 3D cube and is not just the 3D cube turned upside down.
I basically tried applying the 1/(1-v) multiplied by each of the 4th dimension, then apply the 1/(1-w) multiplied by each of the 3rd dimension then finally (1/(1-z)) multiplied by x and y and get my final x,y and the image stay generally the same just upside down

Comment: We can’t tell you if you’re doing “it” right unless you are more specific about what “it” is. “Project 5D points onto a 2D image” isn’t much to go on. Describe the result that you’re trying to get.

Comment: thanks for commenting, I just added a little more description... too long to comment

Comment: Apply a 5D rotation matrix to the points $(x_i , y_i , z_i , h_i , s_i , v_i)$, and project *that* to 2D.  You can even do [orthogonal projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)#Orthogonal_projections) by using the first two coordinates only for the rotated points. You could use the three other coordinates for the hue, saturation, and value, so the three extra spatial coordinates would be indicated by color information... Would be funky, especially as an animation.